# C++ code for a simple single header logging library

Tags: c++, c++11, logging

I have been working out on C++ code lately just for fun and decided to make a simple logger in it. The code works fine, but it would be great if someone more knowledgeable could point out any mistakes/bad practices I would have carried along in my code. Also was curious on how I can go about writing testcases for the same and future code.

```
#ifndef ACE_LOGGER_HEADER
#define ACE_LOGGER_HEADER

#include<chrono>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<mutex>

enum LogLevel  { FATAL = 4, ERROR = 3, WARN = 2, INFO = 1, DEBUG = 0 };

class Logger
{
    public:
        static void init(LogLevel priority_level = INFO,bool save_to_file = false,bool console_output = true,std::string log_file_path = "");

        static void Fatal(std::string message);
        static void Error(std::string message);
        static void Warn (std::string message);
        static void Info (std::string message);
        static void Debug(std::string message);

    private:
        static bool initialized;
        static bool console_output;
        static bool save_to_file;
        static LogLevel    priority_level;
        static std::string log_file_path;
        static std::mutex  logger_mutex; 

        Logger(){}
        
        static Logger get_instance();
        static void log(LogLevel log_level,std::string message);
};

#ifdef ACE_LOGGER_IMPLEMENTATION

bool Logger::initialized     = false;
bool Logger::console_output  = true;
bool Logger::save_to_file    = false;
LogLevel    Logger::priority_level = LogLevel::INFO;
std::string Logger::log_file_path  = "LOG.txt";
std::mutex  Logger::logger_mutex;

Logger Logger::get_instance()
{
    static Logger instance;
    return instance;
}

void Logger::init(LogLevel priority_level,bool save_to_file,bool console_output,std::string log_file_path)
{
    if(console_output == false && save_to_file == false)
    {
        //Both console and file outputs disabled. Exiting logger;
        return;
    }
    
    if(save_to_file)
    {
        // Logging to file enabled
        if(log_file_path != "")
        {
            get_instance().log_file_path = log_file_path;
        }
        get_instance().save_to_file = true;
    }
            

    get_instance().console_output = console_output;            
    get_instance().priority_level = priority_level;
    get_instance().initialized    = true;
}

void Logger::log(LogLevel log_level,std::string message)
{
    if (log_level >= get_instance().priority_level && get_instance().initialized)
    {
        logger_mutex.lock();
        bool time_format_avail = false;
        typedef std::chrono::system_clock clock;

        auto now = clock::now();
        auto seconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now);
        auto fraction = now - seconds;
        std::time_t cnow = clock::to_time_t(now);
        auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(fraction);

        char time_str[100];
        if (std::strftime(time_str, sizeof(time_str), "%H:%M:%S:", std::localtime(&cnow)))
        {
            time_format_avail = true;
        }

        if (get_instance().console_output)
        {
            if (time_format_avail)
            {
                std::cout << time_str << milliseconds.count() << " ";
            }
            std::cout << message << std::endl;
        }

        if (get_instance().save_to_file)
        {
            std::ofstream file(log_file_path, std::ios_base::app);
            if (time_format_avail)
            {
                file << time_str << milliseconds.count() << " ";
            }
            file << message << std::endl;
            file.close();
        }
        logger_mutex.unlock();
    }
}

void Logger::Fatal(std::string message)
{
    log(LogLevel::FATAL,"[FATAL]\t"+message);
}

void Logger::Error(std::string message)
{
    log(LogLevel::ERROR,"[ERROR]\t"+message);
}

void Logger::Warn(std::string message)
{
    log(LogLevel::WARN,"[WARN] \t"+message);
}

void Logger::Info(std::string message)
{
    log(LogLevel::INFO,"[INFO] \t"+message);
}

void Logger::Debug(std::string message)
{
    log(LogLevel::DEBUG,"[DEBUG]\t"+message);
}

#endif

#endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Use enum class

By default, C-like enum put their enumerators in the enclosing namespace. And that's not great at all.

From C++11 on, you can use `enum class` instead, to scope those enumerators within the `enum` itself. And you can also take the opportunity to specify the storage type, so that instead of a 4 bytes `int`, you can specify `std::uint8_t`.

#### Singleton, or not

You are mixing static variables, a static instance returned by value, and by-instance static variable access... and that's not how a singleton is done. At all.

You need to pick one of:

- Either static variables.
- Or instance variables with a global instance.

**Do beware** that in either case you need to think about the static initialization (and destruction) order fiasco.

I would advise going with a proper singleton as it avoids defining static variables separately.

#### Avoid redundant parameters

At the moment, you can have 4 distinct combinations of `save_to_file` and `log_file_path` in `init`:

- `false` and an empty path: OK
- `true` and a non-empty path: OK
- `false` and a non-empty path: What does that mean?
- `true` and an empty path: What does that mean?

You've created woes for yourself and your users by allowing nonsensical combinations to slip through.

Instead, just take a `log_file_path` argument:

- If it's empty, don't log to file.
- If it's non-empty, log to the specified file.

#### Use Guard Style

Instead of opening an `if` block at the beginning of the function, indenting the entire content of it, and closing it at the end, it's better to inverse the boolean and exit early:

```
 if (<not activated>) {
     return;
 }

 //  Do the logging
```

It avoids losing yourself in humpfteens levels of indentation, and makes it clear from the get go that *nothing* happens if not activated.

#### Stop opening and closing that file every single damn time

Opening and closing a file are NOT lightweight operations.

Instead of using a `std::string log_file_path` data member, just use a `std::ofstream log_file` one: open it during `init`, and it'll close itself on destruction.

As a bonus, you don't need a `save_to_file` boolean member either! If the `ofstream` is not open, `<<` is a no-op, so no test needed.

#### Time is always available

You are using `strftime` with a fixed-width formatting pattern, hence you know in advance exactly how many characters it'll format -- and you could `assert` it for checking in debug that you're right.

As a result, there's no need for the `time_format_avail` variable: it's *always* available.

#### Avoid catenating strings

Your logging code is inefficient -- taking a string parameter even when not logging -- but that's not a reason to add insult to injury and create *another* string on top.

Your `log` method already receives the log-level, to test whether to log or not, override `operator<<` for `LogLevel` and be done with it.

#### Allow deferred formatting after the check

Sometimes, formatting the log string is expensive (and doubly so when allocating a string). In those cases, it's nice to have the ability to check whether the result will be used.

The simple way is to offer a `IsEnabled(LogLevel level)` method.

Starting from C++11, it's possible to leverage lambdas:

```
template <typename T>
static void LogLambda(LogLevel level, T&& lambda) {
    if (<not activated>) {
       return;
    }

    std::ostringstream stream;
    lambda(static_cast<std::ostream&>(stream));

    log(level, stream.str());
}
```

#### Not Thread-Safe, despite the mutex

The most glaring issue is that your `init` function doesn't lock the mutex. So if one thread calls `init` while another is logging, who knows what happens...

Another issue is that you read the `is_initialized` and `priority_level` variables prior to locking. It's a good idea to do so... but then they need to be atomic (and you can use relaxed loads).

#### Locked too early

Your mutex is locked too early.

In general, it's best to try and minimize the amount of time for which a mutex is locked. This means calculating as much as possible beforehand, and only locking at the last moment.

In your case, this means formatting the time first *and only then* locking before printing to console and file.

#### Logging doesn't go to `stdout`

By convention, `stdout` is for *application output*, which logging *isn't*.

Instead, logging goes to `stderr`, which for this purpose is best accessed via the aptly named [`std::clog`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog).

*Note: The main difference between `std::cerr` and `std::clog` is that `std::clog` is NOT tied to other streams and it's not automatically flushed on end-of-lines.*

#### Should you use `std::endl`?

`std::endl` has 2 effects:

- It pushes a newline character.
- It flushes the stream.

Flushing is not necessarily wrong for logging, but it's expensive so it bears thinking about it.

My recommendation would be to flush based on the level:

- Fatal and Error flush, as they are important.
- Other levels don't, they'll appear soon enough.

You could even make this parameterizable, so that for debugging a crashing application, one can activate flushing for all logs.

Comment: Have made some edits based on the suggestions put forward here https://github.com/Acedev003/cpp_utils/blob/main/ace_logger.hpp. Kindly do review them if possible

Answer (score 10):

## General Observations:

It isn't clear why you are designing this log as a singleton. This allows only a single instance of the log in the program, what if I need multiple logs?

Should it be okay to run the `init()` functions multiple times, there is no test in the `init()` function to see of the object has been initialized previously.

There are no accessor functions so the only way to change the private variables is by calling the `init()` function. This is non-intuitive.

In the `log()` method, construct the string only once and then log it to the proper output channel as many times as you need.

## Prefer `using` Statements Over `typedef`

Rather than create a new type using `typedef` you can achieve the same functionality with the [using statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

```
void Logger::log(LogLevel log_level, std::string message)
{
    if (log_level >= get_instance().priority_level && get_instance().initialized)
    {
        logger_mutex.lock();
        bool time_format_avail = false;
        using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    ...
```

This is more idiomatic in C++.

## Constructor versus `init()` Function

If the class were not designed as a singlton initialization would be much easier with a constructor. There would also be no need for the `get_instance()` function.

It isn't completely clear why the code has an `init()` function rather than using a constructor to achieve the initialization of the class.

```
class Logger
{
public:

    static void Fatal(std::string message);
    static void Error(std::string message);
    static void Warn(std::string message);
    static void Info(std::string message);
    static void Debug(std::string message);

private:
    bool initialized = false;
    bool console_output = true;
    bool save_to_file = false;
    LogLevel    priority_level = LogLevel::INFO;
    std::string log_file_path{};
    static std::mutex  logger_mutex;

    Logger(LogLevel plevel = LogLevel::INFO, bool saveFile = false, bool useConsole=true, std::string logFile = "")
    : priority_level{plevel}, save_to_file { saveFile }, console_output { useConsole}, log_file_path { logFile}, initialized {true}
    { }

    static Logger get_instance();
    static void log(LogLevel log_level, std::string message);
};
```

## Let the Compiler Do the Work

If the order of the enums in LogLevel was reversed there is no need to specify the value:

```
enum LogLevel { DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL};
```

This makes the code easier to maintain.

The constants aren't actually necessary since the code never tries to use the numeric value.

## Possible Optimization

If you are using any optimization this isn't necessary, since the compiler will do it for you, but in `init()` there are multiple calls to `get_instance()` when there really only needs to be one.

```
void Logger::init(LogLevel priority_level, bool save_to_file, bool console_output, std::string log_file_path)
{
    if (console_output == false && save_to_file == false)
    {
        //Both console and file outputs disabled. Exiting logger;
        return;
    }

    Logger thisLog = get_instance();
    if (save_to_file)
    {
        // Logging to file enabled
        if (log_file_path != "")
        {
            thisLog.log_file_path = log_file_path;
        }
        thisLog.save_to_file = true;
    }


    thisLog.console_output = console_output;
    thisLog.priority_level = priority_level;
    thisLog.initialized = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That's a single header implementation in name only, but it isn't a header-only implementation. You need one (and *exactly* one) implementation file that uses some undocumented magic, namely

```cpp
#define ACE_LOGGER_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "ace_logger.h"
```

That aside, your `std::string` arguments should almost all be `const std::string&` instead.

Comment: I think the string arguments might be better as `std::string_view`, avoiding object creation when `const char*` supplied.

Comment: @TobySpeight That would be C++17 though, and the question is tagged [tag:c++11]. If OP is fine with C++17, then yes, definitely!